# @napi-rs/canvas rendered images look pixelated

Tags: node.js, canvas, node-canvas

I'm building a image using @napi-rs/canvas library. When i load local images, then look pixelated.

Like the image below:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAF4k.png)

The small images look pixelated.

I'm loading the local images using

```
const verified = await Canvas.loadImage(
    readFileSync(join(__dirname, "./assets/images/verified.png"))
  );
```

I'm resizing the images too.

```
context.drawImage(verified, 260, 175, 30, 30);
```

It seems that the problem does not occur with images that are downloaded from the internet, such as the avatar.